# Azure trigger function for file share

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-files, azure-triggers

Like we have blob trigger or event trigger for the blob created or deleted in Azure blob storage, I need to have a function which is triggered when a file is uploaded or created in file share.
Blob storage trigger, event grid trigger doesn't work on Azure file share. Can you please suggest on any custom trigger function or any other way to use the trigger functions on file share?

Answer (score 1):

I am making use of timertrigger to check if the files are created in fileshare. So basically, considering the time difference between 2 timer trigger run, I am checking the new files created and performing further operations.

Comment: How do you check for the new files? Are you using some C# code?

Answer (score 0):

No, your requirement is not possiable.

Azure function don't support file share as the condition of the trigger, you can have a look of this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings?tabs=csharp#supported-bindings

> Can you please suggest on any custom trigger function or any other way
> to use the trigger functions on file share?

As far as I know, it seems didn't have a service to do this. You can do something like this: After you send the data to the file share, hit other api or hit the something like httptrigger to do something.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the writer app, nor hook additional API somewhere.